# Add multiple instances of a VueJS component to a template?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm new to VueJS and would like to add multiple instances of the [card component template](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/cards) to the [VuetifyJS PWA template](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/pwa). 
What I tried:

1. I created a **News.vue** file with the card template code.
2. I added a new Vue instance to **main.js**

> new Vue({
>         el: '#news',
>         router,
>         template: '',
>         components: { News }
>       })

3. I added **News** to **index.js**:

> import Vue from 'vue' import Router from 'vue-router' import Hello
>   from '@/components/Hello' import News from '@/components/News'
>
> Vue.use(Router)
>
> export default new Router({   routes: [
>       {
>         path: '/',
>         name: 'Hello',
>         component: Hello
>       },
>       {
>         path: '/',
>         name: 'News',
>         component: News
>       }   ] })

Adding `<news></news>` multiple times to the **Hello.vue** template -to show the News.vue template content- didn't work.
What did I do wrong?

Hello.vue code:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue

Comment: We need the code for `Hello.vue`

Comment: Also, you have 2 paths pointing to the same place, this will generate warnings in the console. I assume you just want the first one (which it will use by default) as the Hello component is the one that will show the news components.

Comment: @webnoob This is the code inside Hello.vue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue

Comment: You said you added `<news></news>` to the Hello.vue template. You've just linked the vuetify code, not your code you've tried it with.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: Hello.vue code. I added the `<news></news>` tags only at the top. `<template>
<v-app id="inspire">
<news></news>
<news></news>
<news></news>
   <v-navigation-drawer
      fixed
      clipped
      app
      v-model="drawer"
    >
[...]
`
Everything else is the same code as in the example: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/docs/blob/master/examples/layouts/google-contacts.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a component to your `Hello.vue` you need to declare it, like so:

```
import News from './path/to/components/News.vue

export default {
  components: {
    News
  }
}
```

You will obviously just add the component prop if it doesn't exist in your existing example or add the `News` variable to the existing one if it does. Based on the link you've provide, you will need to add the component prop - I would do so just below the `props` property.

This will allow you to use `<news></news>` within your template and it will render the content of your `News` component.

There is lots of information on declaring components in the [Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) including information on how to declare globally so you don't have to declare on multiple components.